# Handling questions with no thought or research effort?

Tags: discussion

alternate title: "I can haz info plz?"

Usually around stackexchange, at least the other sites I've been involved in, it's necessary to show some degree of research effort and thought into the question when it is asked.

I've noticed sometimes questions get asked with no real demonstration that they've even tried to google the answer or demonstrate some effort on their part at all.

For example, [this question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/2761/152) is the most recent example of this.

**(1) Is this kind of question (and level of effort) acceptable around here?**

I'm inclined to say no, because these kinds of questions aren't really "high quality" questions in my opinion since they may not add significantly to the community.

**(2) If not, how to we handle them?**

I'm not sure that asking "What did you try" would work here in the same way it would work on, say, stackoverflow. should we consider asking for more detail or just close? Using what reason? too broad?

As an aside, I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate around of this particular example question, but it still would be a good idea to address this in general.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a great point: we need to attract the experts, with expert level questions and answers. In the one you posted, it should be generalized about *how* to find the information, not so much of just a "give me the answer". I think we should be closing these types, showing too little research effort.